# Progress of replicating the sound of Roland vintage drum machines

Tags: sound, drum

I own a Roland 808 and a Roland 909 (originals). I'm thinking of maybe switching to newer clones/replicas but I'm not sure of the objective standard of those. I usually combine the 808 and the 909 for my drum track but recent years I think that computers and hardware clones are getting closer to the real thing. I don't desperately need the money but I also use it less and less. I use Ableton Live and sometimes Cubase and the Focusrite audio interface.

Do you think that I can get (almost) as good sound quality with software or hardware clones and if yes, which ones?

Comment: Which have you tried already? Why weren't they suitable? Shopping requests/product recommendations are generally off-topic right across stack exchange.

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried the built-in Ableton Live and some sampled audio drum loops where the latter sounded very good but cannot be controlled as MIDI can. What should I try? There is software recommendations at stack exchange, that is in fact for recommendations so your comment is not completely true "recommendations are off-topic at stack exchange" when in fact there is a site for software *recommendations* https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ That might very well be a place to ask for a drum machine software or will you again blame for for not trying?